# How to get value of a data-id attribute from selected(different id, same name) datalist (html5) option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" value="" list="department" />
<datalist id="department">
    <option data-id="1" value="arthur"></option>
    <option data-id="2" value="arthur"></option>
    <option data-id="3" value="king"></option>   
    <option data-id="4" value="gabriel"></option>
</datalist>
```

I just need to access the value of 'data-id' from selected datalist option on click of "#button" or any event.
there is a situation: the same value name, but the different data-id. I want to get the correct id. what should I do? think u!

Answer (score 5):

Accessing these values can be done easily in two ways with vanilla JavaScript, and neither conflicts with regular attributes. Either use

- `element.dataset[foo]`
- `element.getAttribute('data-' + foo)` (this one has more legacy support)

Where `foo` is the name of the *data attribute*, i.e. `"id"` in your case

---

An `<input>`, `<datalist>` pair does not enforce a choice be made from the provided `<option>`s and hence does not offer a direct way to see which option was selected, if you want this use a `<select>` instead.

However, you can find if there was an `<option>` which matches the selection by iterating through them and checking against the *value*. Remember that there is also the case where nothing matches.

An example of how you might do this follows

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var output = document.getElementById('output'),
        input = document.getElementById('foo'),
        list = document.getElementById('bar'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.options.length; ++i) {
        if (list.options[i].value === input.value) {
            output.textContent = list.options[i].getAttribute('data-id');
            return;
        }
    }
    output.textContent = 'No match found';
});
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" value="" list="bar" />
<datalist id="bar">
    <option data-id="0" value="fizz"></option>
    <option data-id="1" value="buzz"></option>>
</datalist>

<button id="check">Check</button>
<span id="output">Make choice, click check</span>
```

Comment: your code is good. But I use jquery. My code: <input type="text" value="" list="department" />  
    <datalist id="department">  
      <select name="dpSelect" id="dpSelect" onchange="lookup()">
      <option data-id="1" value="arthur"></option>   
      <option data-id="2" value="arthur"></option>   
      <option data-id="3" value="king"></option>   
      <option data-id="4" value="gabriel"></option>
      </select>
    </datalist>  but onchange does not work!!

Comment: but onchange function does not

Comment: WOW! Such a perfect answer! Really helped a lot in fetching attributes.  I needed the name tag. I got it working like charm. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jquery then **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** should do the job :

```
var id = $( '#department option:selected' ).data( 'id' );
```

Now `id` should  contain the value of the selected option.

**Update**

Also,

1) if you want to make sure that the `id` variable is an integer you should use:

```
parseInt( $( '#department option:selected' ).data( 'id' ) ).
```

2) Change your `<datalist>` element to a `<select>` element. The datalist is used for autocompletion while they are typing whereas the select element would allow you to actually select an option.

Comment: I can't get it. It's "undefined"

Comment: There is no such thing as a selected option from a `<datalist>` as one list can be used by many inputs

Comment: can you show me the full code you are using. That would help identify the problem.

Comment: Yeah, instead of using a datalist element use should use a select element for that would allow you to choose an option.

Comment: Change your <datalist> element to a <select> element. The datalist is used for autocompletion while the select element would allow you to actually select an option.

Comment: source code: [link](https://github.com/paincupid/springmvc/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/widget/formWidget.jsp)

Comment: do u mean that <datalist> can't deal this situation (the same value name, but the different data-id) ?